# How to Delete Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I try to delete an Azure Active Directory I get this screen:

[image]

When I click on the link to enterprise applications, there are none:

[image]

How can I delete this Azure Active Directory?

Comment: Is your account 'Global Admin'?

Comment: Yes it is......

Comment: Refresh your azure portal and try again.

Comment: Done many times.

Comment: Which role do you have in portal from where you trying to delete?

Comment: I am the 'Global administrator'.

Comment: Was the problem resolved? Let me know if you still have problem.

Comment: Not resolved. I think this is a bug in the portal.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass security checking first which make sure that anything on your directory won't impacts your current resource.

***Prerequisite Of Deleting Directory:***

1. Only an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) global administrator can
   delete an Azure AD directory from the portal.
2. There can be no users in the directory except one global
   administrator who is to delete the directory
3. There can be no applications in the directory. Any applications must
   be removed before the directory can be deleted
4. There can be no multi-factor authentication providers linked to the
   directory
5. There can be no subscriptions for any Microsoft Online Services such
   as Microsoft Azure, Office 365, or Azure AD Premium associated with
   the directory

[image]

When you complete above steps then your delete option should look like below screen shot.

[image]

**Note:** Once you finish all the steps above. Only then you can be shown delete option active.other then it will remain inactive. For more details you can have a look this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-delete-howto)